# Alternate keyboard inputs: dwm on Debian

Tags: debian, keyboard, dwm

Currently my laptop's keyboard has some broken keys (<kbd>z</kbd>, <kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd>). When using my Windows partition I know I can just use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-codes to enter the keys or use alternate hotkeys for the respective keys (<kbd>Alt</kbd>- and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Insert</kbd> for copy and paste).  I know that using GTK I can use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>,"hex code".

But what about dwm, how to I input <kbd>z</kbd>, <kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd>?